# How to Bind TextBlock Width when it is part of style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, wpf-controls

I created my own class for AutoComplete and in its Style I made it in such away that if the text is nothing it shows a textblock. Everything works well except when text is nothing the TextBlock is smaller than the AutoComplete Element. I used Stretched="Fill" but this make the TextBlock stretched and the text inside of the textblock will stretched as well and look so ugly. I am thinking of binding the width of the textbloxk to the ActualWidth of the AutoComplete element but problem is that textblock is in the style and I cannot use the ElementName. Is there any way that Bind the width without using ElementName?

Thank you so much

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Aqua">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1">
                <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ComboBoxButton" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Focusable="false">
                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Color="Transparent">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="true"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource AutoCompleteComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush  Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <TextBlock Text="Press F12" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Foreground="Gray" Background="White" FontSize="16" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" x:Name="TestCB" Width="100" Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<TextBlock Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
```

Note: You can't use this for triggers.

Sorry, I didn't notice that it was part of a trigger. In this case, you can use one of these

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"/>
<TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"/>
```

Comment: And note: You have to remove the stretch None in `<VisualBrush Stretch="None">`

Comment: Hi Daniel - 
Thank you so much for your answer, but sadly none of these solve the problem.
Do you have any other suggestion? - Thank you again

Comment: Hi SvenG - If I remove the `<VisualBrush Stretch="None"> ` then the textblcok which is at the back will always be stretched and font size of it's text will change also. This make it look so ugly. Like if the stretch is only in Height then font will be long and so ugly. - Thank you

Comment: Guys I edited the code. If you want to see how it look like just use this XAML code. Thanks again